# Twitter Bootstrap tab function doesn't work in jsfiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I want to use twitter bootstrap tab function in `jsfiddle`.

I added these two URL as external resources from https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

And copy and paste example of the tab function from from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ .

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

But I can't change tab by clicking it, what am I doing wrong?
This is the page I created.

https://jsfiddle.net/fe26/twsrjph1/

Comment: Look at your errors : bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery ...

Just include jquery before calling bootstrap.js

Comment: Thanks, including jquery solve the problem.